# Which Eiffel compilers use Earley parsing

Tags: eiffel, earley-parser

I stumbled upon this post http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/02-04-096
that says there are two Eiffel compilers using Earley parsing. The post is quite old. 
I wonder if anyone here knows which Eiffel compilers use Earley parsers and if they are
still in use? Links are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modern Eiffel compilers that are used in production ([EiffelStudio](https://docs.eiffel.com/book/eiffelstudio/eiffelstudio) from *Eiffel Software* and [gec](http://gobosoft.com/eiffel/gobo/gec/index.html) from *Gobo Eiffel Project* - both open source) parse Eiffel code using the parsers generated by [geyacc](http://gobosoft.com/eiffel/gobo/geyacc/index.html) from the parser description files (here are the links for [EiffelStudio](https://svn.eiffel.com/eiffelstudio/trunk/Src/framework/parser/parser/eiffel.y) and [Gobo](https://sourceforge.net/p/gobo-eiffel/code/HEAD/tree/gobo/trunk/library/tools/eiffel/parser/et_eiffel_parser.y)), a parser generator utility similar to *GNU bison*, that converts a grammar description for an LALR(1) context-free grammar, but is adapted to produce Eiffel code that is type-safe and void-safe. Neither use an Earley parser.